# How do derivatives transform under coordinate changes?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

You have a transformation group acting on the plane, say $SO(2)$, and some curve in the plane, say $(x,u(x))$. The image of the curve is then
$(X(x),U(x))=(x\cos\theta-u\sin\theta,x\sin\theta+u\cos\theta)$.
THe derivative of the new curve can be found by
$$\frac{dU}{dX} = \frac{dU/dx}{dX/dx} = \frac{\sin\theta+u'\cos\theta}{\cos\theta-u'\sin\theta}$$

I'm stuck on what to do with a surface in three-dimensions, say $(x,y,u(x,y))$ begin transformed to $(X(x,y),Y(x,y),U(x,y))$. How do I find the partial derivatives
$$\frac{\partial U}{\partial X} \ \ \mbox{and} \ \ \frac{\partial U}{\partial Y} \ \ ?$$

**EDIT**

I seem to remember two equations with sums of products of derivatives coming from the chain rule. Then they're put into a matrix equation and inverted. Not sure if that's a red herring.

Comment: To differentiate $U$ with respect to $X$, first write $U$ as a function of $X$ and whatever you want to hold constant; partial derivatives aren't otherwise defined, and there's more than one option.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: The problem is that $X$ and $U$ are both functions of $x$ and $y$, so the expression $\frac{\partial U}{\partial X}$ doesn't make much sense. To give this any meaning, you have to write $U$ as a function of $X$, which might not be well defined if $X$ is not injective.

Comment: @PinkPanther Thanks for your help. I worked it out in the end, and posted an answer below for the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want $U_X$ and $U_Y$ then we are thinking of $U$ as a function of $X$ and $Y$, but $X$ and $Y$ are themselves functions of $x$ and $y$, meaning we have
$U(X(x,y),Y(x,y))$.

Differentiating with respect to $x$ and $y$ in turn gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\partial U}{\partial x} &=& \frac{\partial U}{\partial X}\frac{\partial X}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial U}{\partial Y}\frac{\partial Y}{\partial x} \\ \\
\frac{\partial U}{\partial y} &=& \frac{\partial U}{\partial X}\frac{\partial X}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial U}{\partial Y}\frac{\partial Y}{\partial y}
\end{eqnarray*}

In terms of a matrix equation:

$$\left(\begin{array}{c} U_x \\ U_y \end{array}\right) = 
\left(\begin{array}{cc} X_x & Y_x \\ X_y & Y_y \end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c} U_X \\ U_Y \end{array}\right)$$

Inverting this gives
$$\left(\begin{array}{c} U_X \\ U_Y \end{array}\right)=\frac{1}{X_xY_y-X_yY_x}
\left(\begin{array}{cc} Y_y & -Y_x \\ -X_y & X_x \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} U_x \\ U_y \end{array}\right)$$

Comment: Be aware that this might not be defined everywhere (i.e. when $X_x Y_y-X_y Y_x=0$)

Comment: @PinkPanther It will always be well-defined for a local transformation, i.e. a transformation in a sufficiently small neighbourhood of the identity.